# Proper usage of commas?

Tags: grammar, commas

> My day’s been good as well, thanks, if not a little long feeling.

Is that grammatically correct or am I expected to break it apart into two sentences, leaving the “if” section to stand alone? I feel that it looks wrong, but I also feel that the “if” section belongs with the sentence.

^ Is that grammatically correct? I am skeptical about the comma before “but”. My English teachers didn't teach me well enough . They would always just dock points and never explain why.

Answer (score 2):

First things first, I think certain parts of the sentence should be rephrased. “Long feeling” is not a combination of words that is traditionally used in English. Instead, I think the sentence should be rephrased like this:

> My day has been good as well, thanks, but it has felt somewhat drawn-out.

Judging by the way this sentence is phrased, I’m guessing it is being used in a conversation. In this case, thanks is being used as an informal interjection in the middle of the sentence (http://www.dictionary.com/browse/thanks), so it must be seperated with commas.

Otherwise, your second paragraph was grammatically correct.

Answer (score 1):

See [here](http://www.businessinsider.com/a-guide-to-proper-comma-use-2013-9) for more information about commas.

For example for usage of commas:

> Well, I don't know.

**Note: Following is the edited content of the first answer.**

First, I think certain parts of your sentence should be rephrased. “long feeling” is not a combination of words that is traditionally used in English. I think the sentence should be rephrased like this:

> My day has been good as well, thanks, but it has felt somewhat drawn-out.

In this case, "thanks" is being used as an informal interjection in the middle of the sentence (see [here](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/thanks) for more info), so it **must** be seperated with commas.